# why does jQuery's .html("abc") only insert temproarily?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an html button that calls a function, however when the buttons clicked, the inserted div only appears for a second and then disappears, both visually and in the html tree.

```
function openBox () {

$( '#0' ).click( function () {

    var container = 
    $( "<div>" ).css({
        height : "200px",
        width : "200px",
        position : "absolute",
        "background-color" : "black",
    });

     $( 'button.box' ).html( container );
});
}
```

if i insert the div created in JS into 'button.box' it displays only temporarily, for a split second. the html looks as such:

```
<div class="holder">
  <button id="0" class="box fa fa-paint-brush"></button>
</div>
```

but if inserted into 'div.holder' with the same html structure however, the box displays continuously as expected, but the button is gone.

What is the reason for the button disappearing with continuous display of box & the temporary display of box in their respective circumstances, and what can be done about the button disappearing?

Comment: If your `<button>` is in a `<form>`, it's probably submitting it. Add `type=button` to the `<button>` HTML to prevent that. The default button type is "submit".

Comment: Since you are adding the HTML absolutely positioned, guessing `button.box` does not have relative positioning so it disappears. When you use `html` on holder it replaces everything inside, so you would need to append.

Comment: @Pointy button type was the issue, unable to upvote your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the new container to the `.holder` class, the button disappears because the `.html()` method is *replacing* the content in the selected element. In order to add the box and keep the button, `.append()` is the appropriate jQuery method.

The code below implements what I understand to be the desired outcome; the new div appearing after the button. The new `<div>` is appended to the existing `<div>`, after the button by using `$("button").parent()` to select the existing `<div>`. Appending the new `<div>` to the button itself `$("button").append()` will add the div to the inside of the button.

```
<div class="holder">
    <button id="0" class="box fa fa-paint-brush" type="button"></button>
</div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#0').click( function () {
        var container = $( "<div>" ).css({
            height : "200px",
            width : "200px",
            position : "absolute",
            "background-color" : "black",
        });
        $(this).parent().append( container );
    });
});
</script>
```

More information about the jQuery `append` method, and others, can be found in their documentation: http://api.jquery.com/append/